# Excel Formulas Advice/Suggestion

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Good day
I have the Excel im working on mothly basis. In that Excel I run 2 Formulas. One SumIF and one CountIF. In both I have to change each month the range criteria.

Is there a way to make this more easy to add a button or another command that will replace in the formula the values in range criteria?

Example: in January for my **CountIF** Formula my criteria are: `$C$2:$C$4,` In February i want my Criteria to be `$C$5:$C$6.`

For my **SumIF** my criteria are: `$C$2:$C$4` & `$M$2:$M$4` In February i want my Criteria to be `$C$5:$C$6` & `$M$5:$M$6`.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't call my answer clean but it will work and it avoids hard coding in the formula, If you need to change the range at any time you can just change it in the lookup table. You can implement the same for both your solutions.

If you have a lookup table with the month number looking like this

[image]

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(MONTH(TODAY()),Table2[#All],3,FALSE)&":"&VLOOKUP(MONTH(TODAY()),Table2[#All],4,FALSE)))
```

You can recreate with your language for the SUMIFS and CountIFs with the same logic.

**MONTH(TODAY())**

This will return the current month number that the Vlookup uses.

**INDIRECT**

This allows you to use the string as a lookup

[image]

**VBA**

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684155/excel-vba-find-and-replace

Comment: Great reply, but it doesn't help me at my case. You see I don't now the cells I will populate each month. those cells are the Ticket for service I will open for calls about issues with hardware machines

Comment: So you want the start and end date cell range to populate automatically ?

Comment: if that's possible sure. if there is a formula able to see the new values that have been populated the current month compered to the last month.
My initial idea as you can see in the photo was to have some formulas that will replace the Xth character in the formula with the new numbers i want.

Comment: If you want to go down that road, why not use the find and replace option, search for `$C$2:$C$4` and replace with `$C$5:$C$6`?, you could get the min and max cell based on the date if everything is sorted correctly.

Comment: That what I would do (and i'm currently doing) if I was the only user with access and data entry privileges.
I want to dummy it down as much as possible. and give no reason to anyone to mess with the formulas.

Comment: Well now im lost as a find and replace button in VBA will modify the formula which is what you don't want?
Check out the VBA alternative to find and replace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684155/excel-vba-find-and-replace

Comment: I do not want the user to change anything in the cells manually. I do not trust them.
a VBA command i can Trust. just enter "that" in the box and it will replace "this" no more, no less.

Comment: The link above will do that with tweaks for your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $'s and your formulas will become *relative* -- in other words, when you copy and paste the cells with the formulas down two rows/columns, the coordinates will shift by the same number of rows/columns (note that row and column can be separately defined as either).

Since it seems you're consistently using two rows per one month increment, you can merge two cells per Month for your header column; this way, you can just select and copy each month, which auto highlights both rows, and paste/insert directly beneath previous entry.  Better yet, structure your range that way and just enter the first month value as *Date* data type, e.g., 01/01/2020, then navigate directly to *Custom* data type and format as, e.g., MMM.  You should be able to drag down to have it fill be series (need to confirm later, can't remember off top of my head).

Answer (score 0):

@Arciic
Thanks for your reply.
I do not want to remove the $ cause i run this in many Cells.

I'll upload a picture to better see my excel.
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH4Cs.png)

hope this will help to understand what i would like to do.